# Is there a way to see all the project using a maven dependency?

Tags: maven

I am working on a research project and I need to find some case studies to test my tool.
A great way to find such case studies would be to look for all the projects that use a given maven dependency.

Is there any website where I can query for example for "All the projects depending on guava"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com) will also list the artifacts that directly depend upon a certain artifact.